# CSS: position:relative element encroaches over the top of another element

Tags: css, css-position

I am trying to make [this Wordpress site](http://masterwindowcleaners.com.au/) responsive, by adding the following custom CSS:

```
@media (max-width:959px) {
    .container, #menu, #featured, .slide .overlay, .slide .overlay2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto;
    }
    #menu {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

However, when I move the width of the browser view port to 900px say, `#menu` (the top navigation menu) will increase in height to accommodate `#menu`'s `LI` elements which have floated down and left, but `#content-full` (the parent container of the image slider) will creep up over the bottom half of `#menu`, hiding the `LI` elements which have been pushed down and left.

The theme contains:

```
#content-full {
  position: relative;
}
```

So why does #content-full act like it is `position: absolute`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the content but with the header. The `#header` has an attribute `height: 134px`. And the `#menu` inside this header has been given `position: absolute`. Since absolutely positioned elements are taken out of context before rendering, the parent (in this case `#header`), would not grow to accommodate the height of `#menu` as expected. That is the reason why the height has been explicitly specified. The content is not behaving as absolutely positioned. It is the aforementioned behavior of the header that makes it look like that.

One workaround this could be to provide an additional style that changes the height of `#header` to accommodate the next row of the menu.

Something like this for `max-width: 959px`

```
#header {
    height: 174px;
}
```

This would take care of the second row of menu items. 
Note: Your background image used for the menu would then break. Because it has been made for that single row of menu. I would suggest replacing that background image, with CSS-gradients and rounded borders.